# Android Application with only Service

Tags: android

I need to make an application "x" that has only service in it(no activity and no broadcast receiver) which can be called from activity of another application "y". I need to ask is it possible because on clicking a button in application "y" service of application "x" must be called but it is not happening. I don't see service running in the android phone. So is it even possible to have a single service in a project and nothing else?

application "y" code

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        if(button!=null){
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startService(new Intent("com.example.sonali.serviceonly.OnlyService"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// Perform action on click
                }
            });
        }
    }
}`

application "x" manifest file
``

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name="com.example.sonali.serviceonly.OnlyService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.sonali.serviceonly.OnlyService"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

``

Comment: its possible. u shud have exported service. share your code

Comment: This is possible, although it could be kind of problem in terms of security on how you're planning on doing the communication/starting of tasks.

Comment: It is possible, however why not just have both in the same application, surely one doesn't work without the other?

Comment: @sush shared the code

Comment: @MarkKeen well it is research work and I am supposed to try it this way, 2 different applications

Comment: how ur sure that service didnt run ?

Comment: this is because you are using `implicit` Intent, which does not work as of android 5+: you have to use `explicit` Intent instead, see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) for more info

Comment: The application doesn't show in running apps. So service is not started else it would have shown. I tried running a service on boot and it shows in running app application "x" 0 processes 1 service

Comment: explicit intent just did it . Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

You have to start service like this.

```
Intent intentService = new Intent();
intentService.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.servicename"));
startService(intentService);
```

You must have to set this exported as true in menifest file.

```
 android:exported="true"
```

I have tested it's working fine on 4.4.4 Version.

Try Explicit Intent for version 5+

```
ComponentName n = new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.OnlyService");
Intent a = new Intent();
a.setComponent(n);
a.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
a.putExtra("destinationAddress","5554");
ComponentName c = getApplication().startService(a);
if(c==null)
{
   Log.e("error", "failed to start with " + a);
}
```

Comment: You did like this **startService(new Intent("com.example.sonali.serviceonly.OnlyService"));**. just try with my code, it's working

Comment: Ok, will revert back after trying. cross fingers!

Comment: The toast comes up but I still can't see application "x" in running apps

Comment: @mine0901 check my updated answer, show me your menifest file of service app

Comment: manifest file is given in the question above. You have written no need to add process. It isn't added.

Comment: @mine0901 print something in your services and check is execute or not?

Comment: I gave a toast in onstartcommand in service but it didn't work. Well after using explicit intent instead of implicit the service started.

Comment: @mine0901 i just checked it's working fine on 4.4.4. on which version you are checking ?

Comment: @mine0901 if still not working then make simple activity with simple content, I think we need to open app at once for start service.

Comment: I have version 5.1.1 . It worked after explicit intent.

Comment: Well solved by someone's comment. You can edit your answer 'to try explicit intent for version 5+. Surely will accept it.

Comment: @mine0901 give your start service code so I will update my answer

Comment: ComponentName n =  new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.OnlyService");

                    Intent a = new Intent();
                    a.setComponent(n);.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); a.putExtra("destinationAddress", "5554");
                    ComponentName c = getApplication().startService(a);
                    if (c == null) { Log.e("error", "failed to start with "+a);
                    }